# Could an American presidential election be overturned by state legislatures?

Tags: united-states, constitution, electoral-college

If a political party (Party A) has a nominee that Party B does not like and Party A’s candidate wins by a relatively small electoral margin (318 to 220), can party B appoint sham electors to vote for their candidate? Here’s what I mean: using control of state legislatures to get its candidate into office. So, they would hypothetically have enough control to get them elected. As far as I know, the constitution of the US doesn’t explicitly prohibit such a move.

Comment: Related: Wikipedia article on 2016 ["faithless electors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithless_electors_in_the_2016_United_States_presidential_election).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if this were to be done, Congress has to confirm the result of the electoral college vote before it becomes official.

Some detail in this other question: [A small set of questions on objections to the Electoral College vote by members of Congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13550/a-small-set-of-questions-on-objections-to-the-electoral-college-vote-by-members)

So, while it's possible for state electors to be picked for undemocratic reasons, the assumption is that a member of Congress would raise issue with it and not count those votes.

Comment: But what if the party that was awarded the presidency had a majority in the House. Is there any constraint on their ability to ignore these objections (aside from shame and respect for democracy, which is no longer a given)

Comment: It's interesting that in the only example known when this Congressional objection succeed (1872), the results from the objected-to states were discarded, but as far as I can tell, not reallocated in some way. So a state legislature could still pull some kind of "nullification" of the vote in its state in that perspective.